# Is there an equivalent for the C# IAsyncEnumerable<T> in Python?

Tags: c#, python, .net, async-await, enumerable

I am wondering is there an equivalent of the C# 8 Async Stream interface `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` in Python? That is, a sequence from which each item is retrieved from an `async` source.

For example, let's say there is a remote file `F` on a server `A` and we can read each line of this file asynchronously from a server `B` running a web api, without having to keep the whole file in memory and transforming each line on retrieval before returning the transformed lines, line by line on the web api resource `R`, a bit like a stream of data which would be transformed by the web api resource.

For example: `https://baseUrl/api/transform?fileUri={<FILE_URI>}`

I would like to achieve that with a Python web api (be it [AIOHTTP](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io) or [quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart)).